# Failed to bind radio buttons to view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have posted my code here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/2Ys5j/4/).
Here,I am trying to bind radio buttons (gender) to view but i don't have any idea how to perform binding?

On add it should provide option to select gender but at present by default female is getting select.

Even on save it is not saving any data in model.

```
male: function(){
    return this.get('gender') == 'Male';
}.property('gender')
```

Can any one help me to make  above fiddle work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by defining a view

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({

classNameBindings : ['active'],
attributeBindings : ["value"],
click : function() {
    this.set("selection", this.get('value'))
},
active : function() {
    return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");   
}.property('selection')
```

});

Here is your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raj_Michaels/2Ys5j/7/)

Hope it helps..